# Visible Grid line in the application

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you remove the visible line around the drawing?

It is visible in the running application

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" vm1:SizeObserver.Observe="True" vm1:SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding GW, Mode=OneWayToSource}" vm1:SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding GH, Mode=OneWayToSource}" ShowGridLines="False">
    <Canvas Name="B4" Visibility="{Binding B4Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Width="{Binding B3Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="{Binding B3Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="{Binding A3r, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="{Binding L3r, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Fill="#B4B7B8"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="{Binding A_LX4r, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="{Binding L_LY4r, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Fill="#FF303030"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note, it's pointless to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on OneWay Bindings. That setting only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. It has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Clemens Good advice, Do you think that setting `Top` and `Left` to `-1` and increasing `Width` and `Height` increase by `1` will be good? `<Rectangle Canvas.Top="-1" Canvas.Left="-1" Width="{Binding A_LX4r}" Height="{Binding L_LY4r}" Fill="# FF303030" />` It fulfills its task but is it correct?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a problem with graphics rendering.

Comment: No, just set the Rectangle's StrokeThickness to zero. It is `1` by default.

Comment: @Clemens I've checked and it does not work. I also tried to change the color of the frame so that it would not be visible and there was no result

Comment: You may also try to set UseLayoutRounding="False".

Comment: @Clemens It does not help

Comment: `SnapsToDevicePixels` ?

Comment: @Sinatr That was it. Now it's ok. I've added `SnapsToDevicePixels="true"` to Canvas

Answer (score -1):

This is caused because WPF allows component sizes and positions in fractions of pixels.

For the cure, set `UseLayoutRounding` on your Window to true.

In my opinion this should always be the default value for all Windows, unless you have very good reason, along with `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` and `TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"`. I make a global Window style that includes these.